# Copy from USB drive to USB drive faster

Tags: file-transfer

I need to copy big files from one USB drive to another USB drive. Is there a way to accelerate the data transfer by copying passing just into the hub and not in the OS?

Something like this : USB -> HUB -> USB instead of USB -> HUB -> OS -> HUB -> USB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for a fairly simple reason: the OS (file system driver) has to assign locations on disk to every sector of the file. You can copy the contents, but not the locations on disk (that would end pretty horrible!). USB doesn't even know about files; it sees a USB drive as just a large collection of blocks. Which blocks logically belong together is someone else's concern.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible and I believe there is no difference in speed between  USB -> HUB -> USB instead of USB -> HUB -> OS -> HUB -> USB if your operation system is not being overloaded during the copying session.